# .NET compiler and "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Why in code like below is the .NET compiler not able to establish that all code paths do return a value?

```
bool Test(bool param) {
    bool test = true;
    if (param)
        test = false;
    else
        test = false;
    if (!test)
        return false;
}
```

error CS0161: Not all code paths return a value!

The code can be refactored - but the compiler is not suggesting that.  Yet all return paths are covered - so why does the compiler complain that they are not?

Edit: I guess the conclusion here is that:

```
(error CS0161) + (all code paths obviously return a value) => refactor code.
```

Once you get the habit of that translation I guess everything is ok.

Comment: I guess the devs didn't feel the need to cater for code like this.

Comment: Is there an actual snippet of *useful* code for which you're seeing this compiler error?

Comment: Yes you can add a few lines of code to the above to make it non-trival/genuinely useful but with the over all trait that all code paths return but compiler still complains.

Comment: But it could still be trivially refactored to eliminate redundancy. And then I suspect it would no longer trigger the error. Think of it like a subtle nudge to follow [good design practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: If you the programmer know that `test` will always be false at the line `if (!test)`, then you should remove that line.

Comment: Yes but why is something that is so clearly obvious to a human eye not picked up by the compiler?

Comment: This function in it's current state is useless as `if (!test) return false` should ONLY be `return false`. I'm not seeing any value in trying to understand why a useless function is throwing a warning/error.

Comment: In response to your edit: dtb's answer is correct. Eric Lippert's article not only says that "the reachability analyzer is not very smart" but also that "This shortcoming of the language design is silly, but frankly, we have higher priorities than fixing this silly case."  The solution here is not to fix the compiler; rather, it is to remove the `if (!power_args_ok)` line.  Alternatively, you can throw a `new Exception("power_args_ok is unexpectedly true")` to protect yourself against buggy edits to this method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the C# Language Specification 4.0 included with Visual Studio 2010.

> 10.6.10 "Method body":
>
> When the return type of a method is not void, each return statement in
>   that method’s body must specify an expression that is implicitly
>   convertible to the return type. The endpoint of the method body of a
>   value-returning method must not be reachable. In other words, in a
>   value-returning method, control is not permitted to flow off the end
>   of the method body.

The definition of *reachability* is here (emphasis added):

> 8.1 "End points and reachability":
>
> If a statement can possibly be reached by execution, the statement is
>   said to be reachable. Conversely, if there is no possibility that a
>   statement will be executed, the statement is said to be unreachable.
>
> ...
>
> To determine whether a particular statement or end point is reachable,
>   the compiler performs flow analysis according to the reachability
>   rules defined for each statement. The flow analysis takes into account
>   the values of constant expressions (§7.19) that control the behavior
>   of statements, but **the possible values of non-constant expressions
>   are not considered**.

Since `!test` isn't a constant expression (even though it will always evaluate to `true`), the compiler is obliged to not consider it in the flow analysis. One reason (maybe the only reason) for this restriction is that performing this kind of flow analysis is impossible in the general case.

To get rid of the error, you'll need to have another `return` statement, either in an `else` clause or unconditionally at the end of the method.

Comment: Well I guess that spells it out.  Im just suprised that there is zero depth anaysis of non-constant expressions.  I can understand that the analysis could get complicated quickly but its odd the compiler doest run through a few shallow / trivial cases.

Comment: @Ricibob: The more accurate we make the reachability analyzer, the harder it is for the specification to clearly describe it, and therefore the harder it is for you to know whether your program is correct or not. The language as it is specified today attempts to inhabit the "sweet spot" where the algorithm is understandable, and it catches most reachability errors. Minimizing the number of "false positive" errors is not very high on the priority list. Moreover: the error is pointing out to you an opportunity to improve the code; be happy about that!

Answer (score 10):

From [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx):

> The reachability analyzer is not very smart. It does not realize that there are only two possible control flows and that we've covered all of them with returns.

<sup>(The blog post is on `switch` statements, but I guess the reachability analyzer isn't much smarter for `if` statements.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This just represents the limitations in how smart the compiler is with regard to what gets initialized and which lines will be executed.

I run into this from time to time. But it's very seldom that it's a problem. I would normally just restructure the code a little.

Answer (score 1):

Let's backward analyze the code:

***Problem:** Code doesn't return any value.*

**Question:** Where in code a value is returned?

**Answer:** Just at the last line.

**Conclusion:** So that line of code (last line) should always return a value.

**Question:** Does last line always return a value?

**Answer:** No, it only returns value if `test` is `false` while it has been set to `true` at the first line.

**Conclusion:** As compiler says, this function never returns a value while it is supposed to return `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going in much detail let me answer you question straight.

1. Return type of function is specified as **Bool** hence the
   function must return True or false
2. **Param** has been defined as input parameter hence its value can
   not be determined at compile time
3. value of **test** variable is dependent on param and as per
   step-2, **param** value can not be determined at compile time and hence value of **test** can not be determined at compile time
4. As value of test is not known as compile time(as per step-3)
   hence it start looking for a else / default root for **if (!test)** and
   hence it throws error.

thanks