# warning: control reaches end of non-void function. C Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, while-loop, return, binary-search-tree

I have an insert function for a Binary Search Tree and i can not find out why i am getting that error. Even if i put a return FALSE; right before the function ends it still happens. Any help is appreciated.

```
boolean insert(NODE **root, Employee e){
NODE *cursor,*temp;
// boolean status;

temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
assert(temp != NULL);

temp->element = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
assert(temp -> element != NULL);

*(temp -> element) = e;
temp -> left = NULL;
temp -> right = NULL;

if (*root == NULL) {
    *root = temp;
    return TRUE;
}

// tree is non-empty
cursor = *root;
while (cursor != NULL) {
    if(e.ID < cursor -> element -> ID){
        if(cursor -> left == NULL){
           cursor -> left = temp;
           return TRUE;
        }
        else cursor = cursor -> left;
    }

    //e goes to the right
    else {
        if (e.ID > cursor -> element -> ID){
           if(cursor -> right == NULL){
              cursor -> right = temp;
              return TRUE;
           }                        
           else
              cursor = cursor -> right;
        }
        else { // e is already in the tree
           free(temp -> element);
           free(temp);
           return FALSE;
        }
    }
   }  // while cursor != NULL
 } // insert
```

Comment: There are paths through your code that don't hit a `return` statement.

Comment: Or at least, the compiler can't prove that there aren't.

Comment: "Even if i put a return FALSE; right before the function ends it still happens." Can you post where exactly you put the `return FALSE;`? If you put it _after_ the `while` loop, the diagnostic would be wrong. But it's more likely that you accidentally put it inside the while loop than that the compiler gets such a thing wrong.

Comment: Your right if i put a brace at the end it works, but i still feel like the code should return something before it gets that far.

Comment: If you put a `return FALSE;` just before the end of the function the warning goes away. Perhaps you didn't save the file after making change when you tried that (I'm not ashamed to say that that kind of thing has happened to me at times).

Answer (score 0):

Even though a function actually *does* return something on all possible paths, the compiler can't necessarily determine that - to be able to do so in all cases would effectively prove the halting problem to be solvable. That's why this diagnostic is a warning, not an error.

Here's an example of a function that is easily seen to always return `0`, but many compilers that try to warn you about unhandled return paths will issue the warning:

```
int foo( int x)
{
    while (x >0) {
        --x;
    }
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    while (x < 0) {
        ++x;
    }
    if (x == 0)  return 0;
}
```

However sometimes a simple analysis can determine that all control paths do return a value. The following will typically not generate a diagnostic:

```
int bar(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

In a function as complex as yours, it can be very difficult anyone (compiler or human) to determine that the `while()` loop never terminates except via a `return` inside it.  You may want to add an assertion that always fails after the `while` if you expect that to be the case.  Also you might consider changing the `while (cursor != NULL)` to `for (;;)` which 'documents' that this is a loop that will only end because of a `return` or `break` statement inside (and maybe have an `assert(cursor != NULL)` at the top).

Just for the record, putting a `return FALSE;` just before the end of your function does silence the warning.

Comment: On a related note, see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10114258/12711 for a question about C#'s handling of return paths.  The C# specs requires to the compiler to make certain checks for the return path of a function, with limitations on how 'far' the compiler will check.  In C#, a function similar to the one in the question without a `return` at the end would be an error rather than a warning.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I was using a new compiler and was worried about the warnings.